# How do I fix the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error with Homebrew Apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, homebrew, virtualhost

I have spent far too many hours trying to get virtual hosts to work on my Mac. 
I have a similar setup on Windows 10 using XAMPP and it works with no problems.

Operating System: OS X Ventura 13.4

I need to have two separate local websites. Files are located here:

- Users/myusername/Repos/folder-a
- Users/myusername/Repos/folder-b

I Installed:

- Xcode Tools
- Homebrew
- Apache
- PHP

I have also tried XAMPP and MAMP making similar adjustments. Nothing works. **What am I missing???**

I have added them to the **/etc/hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1               localhost
255.255.255.255         broadcasthost
::1                     localhost

127.0.0.1   mydomain-a.local
127.0.0.1   mydomain-b.local
```

I have made the following edits to: /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 80

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
#LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
#LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

User myusername
Group staff

ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Repos"
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Repos">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Added to /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/**httpd-vhosts.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Repos"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Repos/folder-a"
    ServerName mydomain-a.local
    ServerAlias mydomain-a.local
    <Directory "/Users/myusername/Repos/folder-a">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Repos/folder-b"
    ServerName mydomain-b.local
    ServerAlias mydomain-b.local
    <Directory "/Users/myusername/Repos/folder-b">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**localhost works**

I get this **error message** when I visit mydomain-a.local, mydomain-b.local, mydomain-a.local/index.php, mydomain-b.local/index.php

```
This site can’t be reached
mydomain-a.local refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**sudo apachectl configtest** returns

```
SyntaxOK
```

**sudo apachectl -S** returns:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
         port 80 namevhost mydomain-a.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:28)
                 alias www.mydomain-a.local
         port 80 namevhost mydomain-b.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:39)
                 alias www.mydomain-b.local
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/myusername/Repos"
User: name="myusername" id=501
Group: name="staff" id=20
```

I can **ping** all of them

```
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.032/0.078/0.107/0.033 ms

--- mydomain-a.local ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.031/0.077/0.116/0.033 ms

--- mydomain-b.local ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.026/0.080/0.113/0.033 ms
```

**brew services** returns

```
httpd   started root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
php@7.4 none         
php@8.0 none
```

**php -v** returns

```
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Apr 26 2023 19:18:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

*I know 7.4 is deprecated but I need it for a project*

**Please Help!**